# How I Delete File after uploading in ASP.net FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string savePath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload_File\\");
// Get the name of the file to upload.
string fileName = email_attach.FileName;
string pathToCheck = savePath + fileName;


email_attach.SaveAs(pathToCheck);

string file = pathToCheck;
Attachment data = new Attachment(file);
mail.Attachments.Add(data);

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
email_attach.Dispose();
FileInfo file_Delete = new FileInfo(pathToCheck);
if (file_Delete.Exists)
{
    file_Delete.GetAccessControl();
    file_Delete.Delete();
}
```

when i did this it throws exception like

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Email_Sent_Web\Upload_File\DMP.edx' because it is being used by another process.

how i solve plz help ,thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write `data.Dispose();` below  `mail.Attachments.Add(data);`